# How can we allow wind to pass through but prevents outsiders from seeing into

Tags: wind

I lived in an apartment. The wind feels good. However, we only feel the wind when we open the door.

We want to allow the wind to pass through but we do not want to allow others to see inside our apartment.

How do we solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have any windows?

Comment: @iLikeDirt, some apartments only have windows on one side of the unit which limits the cross breeze.  If the door happens to be on the opposite side than the windows, opening the door will give a really nice cross breeze.

Answer (score 2):

Why not hang a [bi-fold louver door](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Masonite-Plantation-Full-Louver-Painted-Pine-Interior-Closet-Bi-fold-Door-11413/202505872) on the inside. You would hinge it on the opposite side of the door jamb from the existing door. Then, when you open your regular door, you slide the louvered door into the opening and use a hook latch to keep it closed.

```
 Links are examples only, and not an endorsement of any product or source.
```